Title: Room Database Kapt Errors with Coroutine Return Types
I’m building an app with a Room database and using Kotlin coroutines for DAO methods, but I’m encountering several errors during build:
eg" AndroidStudioProjects\CommunicatorApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\poststroke\communicatorapp\DictionaryDao.java:21: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object).
public abstract java.lang.Object getAllWords(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull"
I was getting a No Dao Entity for Nonexistent class error but rebuilt each part
Here is my DictionaryDao.kt
package com.poststroke.communicatorapp

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Update
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import com.poststroke.communicatorapp.DictionaryWord


@Dao
interface DictionaryDao {

    // Insert a new word into the database
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWord(word: DictionaryWord)

    // Insert multiple words into the database
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWords(words: List<DictionaryWord>)

    /* Query to get all words from the dictionary */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM dictionary_words")
    suspend fun getAllWords(): List<DictionaryWord>

    // Query to get all survival words where 'isSurvivalWord' is true
    @Query("SELECT * FROM dictionary_words WHERE isSurvivalWord = 1")
    suspend fun getSurvivalWords(): List<DictionaryWord>

    // Query to get a specific word by the word value
    @Query("SELECT * FROM dictionary_words WHERE word = :word LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getWordByWord(word: String): DictionaryWord?

    // Update an existing word in the dictionary
    @Update
    suspend fun updateWord(word: DictionaryWord): Int

    // Delete a word from the dictionary
    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteWord(word: DictionaryWord): Int
}


My DictionaryDatabase.kt
package com.poststroke.communicatorapp

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [DictionaryWord::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class DictionaryDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun dictionaryDao(): DictionaryDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: DictionaryDatabase? = null

        // Get the database instance
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): DictionaryDatabase {
            // Return the existing database or create a new one, thread-safe
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    DictionaryDatabase::class.java,
                    "dictionary_database"  // Database name
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}


and my DictionaryWord.kt
package com.poststroke.communicatorapp

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "dictionary_words")
data class DictionaryWord(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,  // Auto-generated ID for primary key
    val word: String,  // Word in the dictionary
    val category: String,  // Category the word belongs to
    var isSurvivalWord: Boolean,  // Whether it's a survival word
    val imagePath: String?,  // Path to the image file (nullable)
    var frequency: Int = 0  // Frequency count (optional)
)


As requested here is the relevant sections of the Build.Gradle file
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    id("kotlin-kapt")  
}

    // Room dependencies
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)  // Room Runtime
    kapt(libs.androidx.room.compiler)  // Room Compiler (Annotation Processing)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)  // Room Kotlin Extensions for coroutine support
}

and the referenced part of the libs.versions.toml file
[versions]
agp = "8.6.1"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.10.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.6.1"
activityCompose = "1.8.0"
composeBom = "2024.04.01"
appcompat = "1.3.1"
recyclerview = "1.2.1"
material = "1.4.0"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
preference = "1.1.1"
room = "2.5.1"

androidx-room-runtime = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-runtime", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-compiler = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-compiler", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-ktx = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "room" }


[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }


I have tried checking the reference names, the entity and Dao tags, adding @Colominfo to the dao file for clarity, and rewriting the suspend functions. I cant get this to build.

Please include the part of your build.gradle files that has what Room dependencies you are using.

Added them to the question

Everything looks fine but as Kapt is depricated now try using KSP and see if it works. Here's official documentation https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp#:~:text=KSP%20%28Kotlin%20Symbol%20Processing%29%20is%20a%20Kotlin-first%20alternative,has%20a%20better%20understanding%20of%20Kotlin%27s%20language%20constructs.

Thank you. switching to KSP worked! @Laser if you put this as an answer ill accept

So As I said everything is fine in your code, but Kapt is depricated now and hence you should migrate to KSP (Kotlin Symbol Processing).
Here is the official documentation link.
Migrate Kapt to KSP
